# Microsoft Graph Filter shared OneDrive files

Tags: rest, onedrive, microsoft-graph-api

Based on the graph [filtering docs](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/3075ae72fc0f54d59e9b9fa715d7049c0a42e919/overview/query_parameters.md), I have been trying to implement the call below. I think my syntax could be off since the filter is not being applied :(, any suggestions folks?

Trying to use the complex entity types with a display name like "John Doe".

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe?$filter=remoteItem/createdBy/user/displayName eq '{DISPLAY_NAME}'
```

Comment: Can you provide the response message?

Comment: I can not provide do to the size. The response message is the same as if I just used `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe` without including the filter.

Answer (score 1):

SharedWithMe is not a resource. It is a function and I don't think you can apply filters on the results of a function (my confidence is about 60% on this answer).

```
<Function Name="sharedWithMe" IsBound="true">
    <Parameter Name="bindingParameter" Type="microsoft.graph.drive" Nullable="false"/>
    <ReturnType Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.driveItem)" Nullable="false"/>
</Function>
```

You'll need to perform client-side filtering.

Comment: can you apply filters on collections in general like the `Collection(microsoft.graph.driveItem)`?

Comment: also is there any planned support for applying filters on function returns in the future?

Comment: Better filtering support for this is on the backlog. If this is something you think is important, please consider adding it on our [UserVoice page](https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/category/89523-developer).